# AddComponent() com parâmetros na Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Bom dia pessoal!

Resumindo, estou tentando utilizar o "new" para construir um Objeto na Unity, mas ele diz que não é recomendado o uso do new para instanciar um objeto e sugere o uso do "AddComponent()", mas eu estou precisando que ao  criar um novo objeto, sejam passados 3 parâmetros. Tentei usar na própria chamada do método "AddComponent("Fulano", "Fire", 1)", mas não funcionou.

Alguém saberia me explicar como passo "parâmetros" no AddComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deverá adicionar o componente ao objecto que pretende e depois deverá chamar um método/função para atribuir/definir os valores desse novo componente.

Exemplo:

```
// a class fulano deverá ter uma funcao init

objecto.AddComponent<Fulano>();
objecto.GetComponent<Fulano>().init("Fire", 1);
```

Também pode referenciar tudo numa linha ( sugestão dada pelo camarada Luiz Veira):

```
objecto.AddComponent<Fulano>().init("Fire", 1);
```

Se precisar mesmo de criar o objecto com um constructor veja o exemplo abaixo retirado de [answers.unity.com](https://answers.unity.com/questions/964518/passing-arguments-into-a-constructor-via-addcompon.html)

```
 public class Foo : MonoBehavior {    
    public static Foo MakeFooObject() {
       GameObject go = new GameObject("FooInstance");
       Foo ret = go.AddComponent<Foo>();
       // do constructory type stuff here, you can add parameters if you want but you're manipulating the instance of Foo from the line above.
    return ret;
    } 
 }
```

Já não trabalho com Unity há algum tempo mas penso que o processo mantêm-se.
Eu optaria pela primeira opção, mas isso agora vai depender da sua necessidade.

Comment: Exato. Só queria comentar que o método `AddComponent` já retorna uma instância do componente `Fulano` criado/adicionado ao game object, de forma que você pode fazer diretamente `objecto.AddComponent<Fulano>().init("Fire", 1);`. :)